# Why does WifiP2pService remove my Wifi Direct group?

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I have an app that runs on 2 phones and allows the user to connect from one to the other using WifiP2p (WiFi Direct). On most phones, it works. Both phones go into peer discovery, they discover each other, one initiates a connection, and the other accepts. But when I try to connect to a Sony LT25i running Android 4.1.2, the pairing fails.

The code for initiating the connection is like this:

```
WifiP2pConfig wifiP2pConfig = new WifiP2pConfig();
wifiP2pConfig.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;

// Try to make a device that supports WifiDirect the group owner,
// so that a legacy device can connect to it as an access point.
wifiP2pConfig.groupOwnerIntent = 10;

// Wifi Protected Setup: Push Button Configuration. The other main option is PIN configuration.
wifiP2pConfig.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;

mWifiP2pManager.connect(mChannel, wifiP2pConfig, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {...
```

## Unexpected group creation, remove network

When the problem occurs, when the initiating device runs the above code to attempt to connect, the Sony shows this interesting tidbit in Logcat:

```
02-02 05:22:55.494 669-781/? E/WifiP2pService: Unexpected group creation,
   remove network: DIRECT-aq-LG Phoenix 2
 isGO: false
 GO: Device: 
 deviceAddress: de:0b:34:f0:11:78
 primary type: null
 secondary type: null
 wps: 0
 grpcapab: 0
 devcapab: 0
 status: 4
 interface: p2p0
```

where "LG Phoenix 2" is the name of the phone initiating the pairing.

For some reason, WifiP2pService **doesn't like the fact that a group is being created, and removes it**. Why?

I looked up the error message "WifiP2pService: Unexpected group creation, remove"
and found [this code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4.2_r1/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pService.java) in `WifiP2pService.DefaultState.processMessage()`:

```
              /* unexpected group created, remove */
            case WifiMonitor.P2P_GROUP_STARTED_EVENT:
                mGroup = (WifiP2pGroup) message.obj;
                loge("Unexpected group creation, remove " + mGroup);
                mWifiNative.p2pGroupRemove(mGroup.getInterface());
                break;
```

So apparently this happens because the WifiP2pService is in `DefaultState`? By contrast, `WifiP2pService.P2pEnabledState.processMessage()` doesn't have a `case` for `P2P_GROUP_STARTED_EVENT`. So maybe if the WifiP2pService were in the P2pEnabledState on the phone, I wouldn't be having this group removal problem.

But according to the logs, WifiP2p *is* enabled: I'm catching the `WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` broadcast and logging the value of `EXTRA_WIFI_STATE`. So why is WifiP2pService apparently in `DefaultState`?

By the way, pairing *used* to work on the Sony, but yesterday I connected the device to my home Wifi router and it doesn't seem to have worked ever since, even though I disconnected it from the router.

I've tried turning off Wifi, turning it back on, removing ("forgetting") my home Wifi router, and rebooting the phones, and connecting from other phones besides the LG. Nothing fixes the problem.

Comment: It supposes that something went wrong, if P2P_GROUP_STARTED_EVENT: comes in DefaultState, and removes connected Group.
What I see is that your group is on error status before removing. Status: 4 is[/* Protocol error. */  INVALID_PARAMETER].

Comment: @SergeyNersesyan I'm not sure I understood all of what you said. But I also don't think the `status: 4` refers to the group at all. Looking at the code for WifiP2pGroup.toString(), the `status` part comes from WifiP2pDevice.toString() describing the GO device. WifiP2pDevice.status = 4 indicates `UNAVAILABLE`.  So this helps, but the question then becomes, why is the device status UNAVAILABLE in this situation, and not for most phones most of the time? BTW the "device address" shown doesn't match the WiFi MAC address of either phone. I'm not sure which device is "UNAVAILABLE".

Comment: I thought that status is WifiP2pService.P2pStatus.INVALID_PARAMETER, but you are right, sorry. staus = UNAVAILABLE is default value, it set in WifiP2pDevice class constructor. I can suggest two things to check, if you are not done yet
1. put brackpoints on WifiP2pDevice.status changes and debug on Sony and on other device to look difference
2. This is quite silly, but maybe you notice variation on your device date/time after connecting to your wifi? I saw that there is time related checks on WifiP2pService.

Answer (score 1):

This code that you have is very incomplete and needs to be completed. Note the sample of the code for you.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.WpsInfo;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pConfig;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDevice;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pInfo;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ActionListener;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.DnsSdServiceResponseListener;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.DnsSdTxtRecordListener;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.nsd.WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.nsd.WifiP2pDnsSdServiceRequest;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.android.wifidirect.discovery.WiFiChatFragment.MessageTarget;
import com.example.android.wifidirect.discovery.WiFiDirectServicesList.DeviceClickListener;
import com.example.android.wifidirect.discovery.WiFiDirectServicesList.WiFiDevicesAdapter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class WiFiServiceDiscoveryActivity extends Activity implements
        DeviceClickListener, Handler.Callback, MessageTarget,
        ConnectionInfoListener {

    public static final String TAG = "wifidirectdemo";

    // TXT RECORD properties
    public static final String TXTRECORD_PROP_AVAILABLE = "available";
    public static final String SERVICE_INSTANCE = "_wifidemotest";
    public static final String SERVICE_REG_TYPE = "_presence._tcp";

    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 0x400 + 1;
    public static final int MY_HANDLE = 0x400 + 2;
    private WifiP2pManager manager;

    static final int SERVER_PORT = 4545;

    private final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    private Channel channel;
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = null;
    private WifiP2pDnsSdServiceRequest serviceRequest;

    private Handler handler = new Handler(this);
    private WiFiChatFragment chatFragment;
    private WiFiDirectServicesList servicesList;

    private TextView statusTxtView;

    public Handler getHandler() {
        return handler;
    }

    public void setHandler(Handler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        statusTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text);

        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter
                .addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter
                .addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

        manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        channel = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
        startRegistrationAndDiscovery();

        servicesList = new WiFiDirectServicesList();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container_root, servicesList, "services").commit();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        Fragment frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("services");
        if (frag != null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(frag).commit();
        }
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (manager != null && channel != null) {
            manager.removeGroup(channel, new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Disconnect failed. Reason :" + reasonCode);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                }

            });
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    /**
     * Registers a local service and then initiates a service discovery
     */
    private void startRegistrationAndDiscovery() {
        Map<String, String> record = new HashMap<String, String>();
        record.put(TXTRECORD_PROP_AVAILABLE, "visible");

        WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo service = WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo.newInstance(
                SERVICE_INSTANCE, SERVICE_REG_TYPE, record);
        manager.addLocalService(channel, service, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                appendStatus("Added Local Service");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int error) {
                appendStatus("Failed to add a service");
            }
        });

        discoverService();

    }

    private void discoverService() {

        /*
         * Register listeners for DNS-SD services. These are callbacks invoked
         * by the system when a service is actually discovered.
         */

        manager.setDnsSdResponseListeners(channel,
                new DnsSdServiceResponseListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDnsSdServiceAvailable(String instanceName,
                            String registrationType, WifiP2pDevice srcDevice) {

                        // A service has been discovered. Is this our app?

                        if (instanceName.equalsIgnoreCase(SERVICE_INSTANCE)) {

                            // update the UI and add the item the discovered
                            // device.
                            WiFiDirectServicesList fragment = (WiFiDirectServicesList) getFragmentManager()
                                    .findFragmentByTag("services");
                            if (fragment != null) {
                                WiFiDevicesAdapter adapter = ((WiFiDevicesAdapter) fragment
                                        .getListAdapter());
                                WiFiP2pService service = new WiFiP2pService();
                                service.device = srcDevice;
                                service.instanceName = instanceName;
                                service.serviceRegistrationType = registrationType;
                                adapter.add(service);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                Log.d(TAG, "onBonjourServiceAvailable "
                                        + instanceName);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }, new DnsSdTxtRecordListener() {

                    /**
                     * A new TXT record is available. Pick up the advertised
                     * buddy name.
                     */
                    @Override
                    public void onDnsSdTxtRecordAvailable(
                            String fullDomainName, Map<String, String> record,
                            WifiP2pDevice device) {
                        Log.d(TAG,
                                device.deviceName + " is "
                                        + record.get(TXTRECORD_PROP_AVAILABLE));
                    }
                });

        // After attaching listeners, create a service request and initiate
        // discovery.
        serviceRequest = WifiP2pDnsSdServiceRequest.newInstance();
        manager.addServiceRequest(channel, serviceRequest,
                new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        appendStatus("Added service discovery request");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int arg0) {
                        appendStatus("Failed adding service discovery request");
                    }
                });
        manager.discoverServices(channel, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                appendStatus("Service discovery initiated");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int arg0) {
                appendStatus("Service discovery failed");

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void connectP2p(WiFiP2pService service) {
        WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
        config.deviceAddress = service.device.deviceAddress;
        config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
        if (serviceRequest != null)
            manager.removeServiceRequest(channel, serviceRequest,
                    new ActionListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(int arg0) {
                        }
                    });

        manager.connect(channel, config, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                appendStatus("Connecting to service");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int errorCode) {
                appendStatus("Failed connecting to service");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                Log.d(TAG, readMessage);
                (chatFragment).pushMessage("Buddy: " + readMessage);
                break;

            case MY_HANDLE:
                Object obj = msg.obj;
                (chatFragment).setChatManager((ChatManager) obj);

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        receiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(manager, channel, this);
        registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo p2pInfo) {
        Thread handler = null;
        /*
         * The group owner accepts connections using a server socket and then spawns a
         * client socket for every client. This is handled by {@code
         * GroupOwnerSocketHandler}
         */

        if (p2pInfo.isGroupOwner) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Connected as group owner");
            try {
                handler = new GroupOwnerSocketHandler(
                        ((MessageTarget) this).getHandler());
                handler.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG,
                        "Failed to create a server thread - " + e.getMessage());
                return;
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Connected as peer");
            handler = new ClientSocketHandler(
                    ((MessageTarget) this).getHandler(),
                    p2pInfo.groupOwnerAddress);
            handler.start();
        }
        chatFragment = new WiFiChatFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container_root, chatFragment).commit();
        statusTxtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void appendStatus(String status) {
        String current = statusTxtView.getText().toString();
        statusTxtView.setText(current + "\n" + status);
    }
}
```

And the file for your AndroidManifast.xml should be the same and give these accesses

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Google Play filtering --> 
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi.direct" android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".WiFiServiceDiscoveryActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

If you have any questions, let me respond as quickly as possible

**SOURCE** 
[WiFiDirectServiceDiscovery](https://github.com/Miserlou/Android-SDK-Samples/tree/master/WiFiDirectServiceDiscovery)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do have those permissions in my manifest (remember, the pairing works most of the time on most phones). Yes, the code I showed is incomplete... it's part of a large app. I suppose I could work on a MWE.

Comment: BTW if you copy a chunk of code from a source that's not written by you, please acknowledge the source. For example, https://github.com/Miserlou/Android-SDK-Samples/tree/master/WiFiDirectServiceDiscovery

Comment: Oh, Sorry I'm really sorry I want the source code in my system and I did not know it   **I edited my reply**  @LarsH